# Find the radius of convergence and interval of convergence for the following power series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{\sqrt n}{(x+7)^n}$

What did I do wrong?

I used the ratio test and got:

2|x+7| < 1

And for my radius I got $\frac {1}{2}$

After, I solved the inequality and got the interval [-15/2,-13/2]

But webwork is telling me I'm incorrect.
I also tried to see if (-15/2,-13/2) would work but it did not.

UPDATE: As the comments suggested I tested the endpoints and the correct interval is:

(-15/2, -13/2]

Comment: This seems correct to me. Perhaps it's an error in the formatting? One potential error might be in the interval notation. Since you use $<$ and not $\leq$, the interval would be better named

$$\left( \frac{-15}{2} , \frac{-13}{2} \right)$$

since you shouldn't be including the endpoints.

Comment: I tried this and it's still telling me I'm wrong :(

Comment: You have to test the endpoints: $x = -15/2$ and $x = -13/2$.  What happens to the series for these $x$-values?

Comment: As suggested above, try the points and use theorems for series given by alternating decreasing in absolute value sequences. One of the two end points gives a convergent series.

Answer (score 1):

To test the end points,

When $x = \frac{-13}2$, the series becomes

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}},$$

since $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ decreases to $0$, by alternativing series test, the series converges.

When $x=\frac{-15}2$, the series becomes $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$$ and by $p$-series test, it diverges.